# Not able to install node_xslt on node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, xslt

I am trying to install node_xslt from command prompt by using

```
npm install node_xslt
```

But I am getting the following error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItxFT.png

There are few prerequisites to install node_xslt:

```
libxml2 
libxslt 
libexslt 
xml2-config (Needs to be on PATH)
```

Also when I tried to install libxml2 and other libraries, I got this error: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxMg0.png

I am not sure where xml2-config file is. It says that it should be in my path.

Comment: This module not compatible with Windows (imho). Try https://github.com/albanm/node-libxslt

Comment: @stdob-- I tried to install node-libxslt by using "npm install libxslt", but it shows:       MSBUILD : error MSB4132: The tools version "2.0" is unrecognized. Available tools versions are "4.0".
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1

Comment: @NupurJaiswal On my windows 7 machine I could install libexslt. Seems you do not have the "right" Visual Studio or node.js version. Also check your node gyp version (https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/wiki/Updating-npm's-bundled-node-gyp) And for MSBUILD error https://github.com/chjj/pty.js/issues/60 may help. But also I had a working xlstpoc (using libxslt, libxml2 ..) long before using node.js - but should not part of the "solution".