# Convert xml to html using XSLT stylesheet in node.js

Tags: html, xml, node.js, xslt, saxon

Has anyone tried to convert xml file into html webpage using XSLT stylesheet in node.js? My background is in Java. I normally use SAXON to convert XML into HTML webpages. I am a newbie to node.js. I have tried to implement this using few libraries like node_xslt, libxsltjs etc but was not successful. If anyone has tried using other libraries that works with XSLT stylesheet, please post a link. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Create a child process in node and run the transformation in Java. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @SureshKoya Thank you for replying. Actually I am working on a project where I am building a web app using node.js and express on the top of elasticsearch. I have converted elasticsearch JSON output into xml. Now, the client wants his frontend to look like a specific frontend. For this reason, I want to use elasticsearch xml output and the XSLT stylesheet to create an html web page. For this reason, I wanted to know if I can use any module from node.js. If it's not possible, I can switch to servlet and use SAXON.

Comment: Certainly a viable way to do it if you don't have much load or need for snappy response. Another thing you can do is offload the transform to the client by returning an xml file with an embedded stylesheet reference. Simple XSL1 works on major desktop browsers and at least iOS on Chrome and Safari

Comment: You should probably take json input and use jade or handlebar templates to generate the html.

Comment: What are the errors you got with node_xslt and why don't you put examples of what did not work?

Comment: There was an installation error. Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36926149/not-able-to-install-node-xslt-on-node-js?noredirect=1#comment61413718_36926149. Also I tried using other libraries but I was not able to implement. I didn't find any good documentation on it.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use Saxon from a Node.js application, you basically have three choices, none of them ideal:

(a) call out to Java, using a variety of mechanisms.

(b) use the port of Saxon/C to Node.js being constructed here: https://github.com/rimmartin/saxon-node This is bleeding-edge stuff and I don't know how far the project has got.

(c) wait for Saxon-JS to arrive any time soon. See http://dev.saxonica.com/blog/mike/2016/02/introducing-saxon-js.html

Comment: Thanks, Michael. I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

At time of writing this works for me...

1. install saxon...

   > npm install saxon-js (see https://www.npmjs.com/package/saxon-js)
2. write a little test program

   `const saxon = require('saxon-js');
   const env = saxon.getPlatform(); const doc = env.parseXmlFromString(env.readFile("styles/listview.xsl"));
   doc._saxonBaseUri = "dummy"; const sef = saxon.compile(doc);
   let xml = "<EMPLOYEE_ID>107</EMPLOYEE_ID><FIRST_NAME>Summer</FIRST_NAME><LAST_NAME>Payne</LAST_NAME>summer.payne@example.com515.123.8181<HIRE_DATE>2016-06-07</HIRE_DATE><MANAGER_ID>106</MANAGER_ID><JOB_TITLE>Public Accountant</JOB_TITLE>";
   let html = saxon.transform({
   stylesheetInternal:sef,
   sourceType: "xml",
   sourceText:xml,
   destination: "serialized"}, "async"
   ).then( output => {
   console.log(output.principalResult);
   } );`
3. run the test program from the command line...

   > node test.js

The output should be the transformed XML.

Luck.